# Which SQL table should I use to store `popularity` field

Tags: sql, django, caching, optimization, e-commerce

I am setting up a small E-commerce website using Django. My aim is to ensure that the landing page displays products in order of `popularity`. I am defining `popularity` as the total number of times a product was purchased.

In terms of design architecture, what is the best way of achieving this?

At first I thought of putting the `popularity` field inside the `Product` table. However, I suspect that I will get in trouble with caching further down the line. Perhaps it is best to create a `PopularityDetails` table with both `product_id (pk)` and `popularity`?

I see many website have this functionality so I would have thought that there must be a standard practice on this. Alas, I have not found any resources on the matter. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a separate table called popularity and assign a fk to product. Everytime a product was purchased successfully, mark it as successful via a Boolean field and assign an order number to differentiate it. There is a lot of way this could be achieved.

Comment: you could use an integer field and increment everytime the item was purchased? like @mar